# How to wrap integrate Microsoft Appcenter's Code-Push in Xcode

Tags: xcode, react-native, visual-studio-app-center

I have a react-native (v0.59.9) application published on the App Store and the Play Store. The `react-native-code-push` library has already been successfully added to the binaries of these initial App Store submissions.

My goal is to actually start using the code-push servers. to do that Microsoft's doc say:

> For React Native 0.59 - 0.59.10: Find the following line of code,
>   which sets the source URL for bridge for production releases:
>   objective-c

```
return [[NSBundle mainBundle]     
URLForResource:@"main"withExtension:@"jsbundle";
```

> Replace it with this line:

```
return [CodePush bundleURL];
```

However my project is RN-v0.59.9, and my appDelegate.m file looks like this:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <CodePush/CodePush.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <ReactNativeNavigation/ReactNativeNavigation.h>
#import "SplashScreen.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
  [ReactNativeNavigation bootstrap:jsCodeLocation launchOptions:launchOptions];

  [SplashScreen show];
  return YES;
}

@end
```

What changes do I need to make to integrate the library completely?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `[CodePush bundleURL]` instead of `[[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil]`

Please refer to the [example app](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/master/Examples/CodePushDemoApp/ios/CodePushDemoApp/AppDelegate.m) for more info.

Comment: The example app you linked to is for react-native version 0.61.5. Will that affect my native integration for either android or iOS? Because as I said, I’m using 0.59.9, and the integration steps in App Center docs are different across react-native versions

Comment: Simply replacing the line I mentioned should do the work.